# How to obtain the virtual machine name using vmtoolsd

Tags: vmware

I want to update network configuration to allow dhclient to provide a client ID or hostname that matches the vm name.  To do this, I need to be able to extract the vm name from vmtoolsd.  I have been searching for a property that you can extract using `vmtoolsd --cmd "info-get ..."` but nothing really works.

Does anybody know how to get the virtual machine name?

Just to clarify, I am not interested in the hostname as reported by vmtools, I want the virtual machine name, that you see when you look at the object browser for a particular vm moid.